# Oh My Zsh install in docker fail

Tags: docker, zsh, dockerfile, oh-my-zsh

I don't know why this line return 1 when I run it a docker file:

```
RUN sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

I have wget install and I don't know why it's return 1 (no error message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea, but you don't have to use the one step install shorthand which might give you a better idea of where the command is failing.

```
RUN set -uex; \
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh; \
    sh ./install.sh; \
    rm ./install.sh
```

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks. A good answer to tell you how to debug instead of only telling you the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the interactive part of the installation script.

You should generate previously `.zshrc`.

```
RUN apt-get install -y zsh
RUN git clone https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh \
    <installation_path>/.oh-my-zsh
COPY conf/.zshrc <installation_path>/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

when you run the following command to install `oh-my-zsh`, the command installed oh-my-zsh successfully and exited with code `1`. (you can run `echo $?` to check).

`sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
echo $? #output 1`

But, the docker build shell thought it's an error when commands execute without returning code 0. To solve it, we can append a zero-returned command after the install command:

`RUN sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"; exit 0;`